# Extract number of length n from field and return string

Tags: text-processing, grep, bioinformatics

I have a tab delimited file with a combination of text and numbers. I want to keep each line as is, but I want to keep only the six digit numbers in the 5th column if present. For example:

```
gene1   NM_033629   598G>A  P912    syndrome  1, 192315 syndrome 2,  225750 syndrome 3 610448   score   AD  hom user    123456  Source
gene2   NM_000459   613G>A  V115I   syndrome 1 600195   score   AD  rec user    234567  Source
```

(Syndrome # is used as an example, this can be any text so not a pattern I can search and remove)

I want the output to be:

```
gene1   NM_033629   598G>A  P912    192315 225750 610448    score   AD  hom user    123456  Source
gene2   NM_000459   613G>A  V115I   600195  score   AD  rec user    234567  Source
```

I have 4 ways to extract the 6 digit number, however, I cannot

a. output the number in the line it originated from

b. successfully print the entire line with the one edited field. The options I have used to extract the digits are:

```
cat inputfile | cut -f 5 |grep -P '(? < !\d)\d{6}(?!\d)'
cat inputfile | cut -f 5 |grep -Po '(?< !\d)\d{6}(?!\d)'
cat inputfile | cut -f 5 |grep -o '[[:digit:]]*'
cat inputfile | cut -f 5 |grep -o "[0-9]\{6\}"
```

I know using cut for the column is incorrect but I wanted to ensure I had the extract correct as there is also a six digit number in field 9. I'm stuck on putting this all together. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the 5th column to become the concatenation with space of all the 6 digit numbers in it.

Maybe:

```
perl -F'\t' -lape '
   $F[4] = join " ", grep {length == 6} ($F[4] =~ /\d+/g);
   $_ = join "\t", @F' < file
```

Or reusing your negative look around operators:

```
perl -F'\t' -lape '
   $F[4] = join " ", ($F[4] =~ /(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)/g);
   $_ = join "\t", @F' < file
```

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '
  {
    repl = sep = ""
    while (match($5, /[0-9]+/)) {
      if (RLENGTH == 6) {
        repl = repl sep substr($5, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        sep = " "
      }
      $5 = substr($5, RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    $5 = repl
    print
  }' < file
```

`grep` itself is not very adequate for the task. `grep` is meant to print the lines that match a pattern. Some implementations like GNU or ast-open  `grep`, or `pcregrep` can extract strings from the matching lines, but that's quite limited.

The only `cut`+`grep`+`paste` approach I can think of that could work with some restrictions would be with the `pcregrep` `grep` implementation:

```
n='(?:.*?((?1)))?'
paste <(< file cut -f1-4) <(< file cut -f5 |
  pcregrep --om-separator=" " -o1 -o2 -o3 -o4 -o5 -o6 -o7 -o8 -o9 \
    "((?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d))$n$n$n$n$n$n$n$n"
  ) <(< file cut -f6-)
```

That assumes that every line of input has at least 6 fields and that the 5th field of each has in between 1 and 9 6-digit numbers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I have not yet had the opportunity to tese however, the output for line 1 field 5 should read: 192315 225750 610448

Comment: I tested the perl solution and it delivered the desired output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";
    OFS = "\t";
}
{
    cnt = patsplit($5, arr, /[0-9]{6}/);
    $5 = arr[1];
    for(i = 2; i <= cnt; i++) {
        $5 = $5 " " arr[i];
    }
    print;
}' input.txt
```

> **patsplit(s, a [, r [, seps] ])** - 
>                                  Split  the  string  **s** into the array **a** and the separators array **seps** on the
>                                  regular expression **r**, and return the number of fields.  **Element values  are
>                                  the  portions  of  s that matched r**.

**Input:**

```
gene1   NM_033629   598G>A  P912    syndrome 1, 192315 syndrome 2, 225750 syndrome 3 610448 score   AD  hom user    123456  Source
gene2   NM_000459   613G>A  V115I   syndrome 1 600195   score   AD  rec user    234567  Source
```

**Output:**

```
gene1   NM_033629   598G>A  P912    192315 225750 610448    score   AD  hom user    123456  Source
gene2   NM_000459   613G>A  V115I   600195  score   AD  rec user    234567  Source
```

Comment: That would take groups of 6 digits from numbers with more than 6 digits.

Comment: Note that `patsplit` is GNU specific

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think, the pattern like `/\b[0-9]{6}\b/` should solve the problem with taking groups from numbers with more than 6 digits. Not tested, though. "patsplit is GNU specific" - yes, it is assumed that `gawk` will be used.

Comment: `gawk` supports `\<`, and `\>` but not `\b` (as `\b` is backspace). That would also not do what we want for input like `ABC123456DEF`. You could search for `/[0-9]+/` and filter out the matches that are not of length 6 like in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This discussion is very educational, I will also look at this solution.